# How to profile QtScript Code?

Tags: javascript, performance, qt, qtscript

I know there are tools to profile pure javascript code like ***firebug*** and ***Chrome's Developer Tools***, but I want to know if there are any good tools for profiling QTScript. Or how can I use these tools to profile QtScript code.

The use case for this is when there is a Desktop app whose most of the code is written in JavaScript with some code written in native QT/C++. In that scenario if someone wants to profile the the performance, what are some tools that can automate the profiling.

Comment: I see this a "what's the best X?" question. For example: "What's the best car?"  

If you're digging out from a snow storm an indy racer isn't very good. If you're trying to win an indy race then a snow plow won't work very well.

The correct question should be "What's the best javascript if I want to do X?". What do you want to do with it?

Comment: @jay I have added some details to the question, tell me if it is not even clear now "what I want do it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are not many tools designed primarily for profiling QtScript.

But there is one *[QscriptProfiler](https://github.com/icefox/qscriptprofiler)* by Benjamin Meyer, I haven't used it personally but looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small QScriptEngineAgent that does the job for me. See my answer in [QScriptEngineAgent - obtaining callee name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27075268/qscriptengineagent-obtaining-callee-name).

Cheers,

Johannes